# How to implement wizard-like navigation flow with Conductor?

Tags: android, conductor

I am building an Android app with Conductor. Let's say the app has the following screens

- Widget List
- Widget Details
- Create Widget: Step 1
- Create Widget: Step 2

How do I implement the following navigation flow with Conductor?

1. User launches app, *Widget List* controller is pushed.
2. User clicks New Widget, *Create Widget: Step 1* controller is pushed.
3. User clicks Go to Step 2, *Create Widget: Step 2* controller is pushed.
4. User clicks Confirm, the widget is created and now I want to pop *Create Widget: Step 1* and *Create Widget: Step 2* and push *Widget Details* for the newly created widget.

If I pop all the way back to *Widget List* and then push *Widget Details*, the *Widget List* will momentarily show before *Widget Details* is shown.

How do I achieve this in a single transaction and take the user straight to *Widget Details* while also simultaneously popping *Create Widget: Step 1* and *Create Widget: Step 2* from the back stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use router.setBackstack() method and using tags when pushing the steps for later filtering:

1. Settings root controller

   ```
   if (!hasRootController()) {
       setRoot(RouterTransaction.with(listController).tag("list"))
   }
   ```
2. Push first controller

   ```
   router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(firstStepController).tag("step1"))
   ```
3. Push second controller

   ```
   router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(secondStepController).tag("step2"))
   ```
4. Push detail controller

   ```
   router.setBackstack(
       router.backstack.filter { it.tag() != "step1" && it.tag() != "step2" } + RouterTransaction.with(detailController).tag("detail")
       SimpleSwapChangeHandler() // Or other change handler for proper animation
   )
   ```